# Can I add context in @Scheduled?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, schedule

This is my code :

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "30 3 * * * *")
    public void myCron() {
        //we don't care what we do here
    }
```

I want to know if it is possible to add a tracking id (or other information) on my `@Scheduled` automatically.

The id will be different each time `@Scheduled` is triggered.

I want to do this to avoid to duplicate code like :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "10 3 * * * *")
public void myCron() {
    MDC.put("myId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    //we don't care what we do here
}
@Scheduled(cron = "30 3 * * * *")
public void mySecondCron() {
    MDC.put("myId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    //we don't care what we do here
}
```

I tired to implements `SchedulingConfigurer` but `SchedulingConfigurer#configureTasks` is too late too add behavior on taks because the task (runnable) is already created

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: As you can see from docs, you cannot put it in `@Scheduled` annotation. Just to be clear, you want to schedule multiple tasks at the same time, and you want to differentiate between those two in logs. is that correct?

Comment: @pvpkiran i want to schedule multiple task but i don't care if it's  on the same time. I want some "ScheduledDecorator" to add behavior before run the task. And yes i want to differentiate them in logs

Comment: what kinda behaviour?

Comment: @pvpkiran This kind `MDC.put("myId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());`

Comment: Honestly I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want the same 'id' in your two crons or what exactly?

Comment: @prettyvoid Sorry if i doesn't explain it well. What i want is to track all my scheduled event. That's mean if `myCron()` is triggered, i want to  associate it with an id "Id1". If `myCron()` is triggered a second time i want to associate it with an other id like "Id42". Is it more clear ?

Comment: @ahammani so just generate a uuid inside the cron? That way each trigger will have a unique id, no?

Comment: @prettyvoid yes i can do that and it works. But if someone add an other `@Scheduled` and forgot to generate an uuid inside the cron then we lost the  tracking. I want a generic/automatic way to do what you said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to implement custom `TaskScheduler` and register it in `SchedulingConfigurer.configureTasks`. `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` can be considered as an example. Unfortunately this class isn't well-designed for inheritance, otherwise `decorateTask` method will be protected. So you need to override all methods to add one additional Runnable decorator with your logic. Something like this one :

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    public static class MyTaskScheduler extends ConcurrentTaskScheduler {

        public MyTaskScheduler() {
        }

        public MyTaskScheduler(ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor) {
            super(scheduledExecutor);
        }

        public MyTaskScheduler(Executor concurrentExecutor, ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor) {
            super(concurrentExecutor, scheduledExecutor);
        }

        // TODO override other methods

        @Override
        public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger) {
            return super.schedule(decorateTask(task), trigger);
        }

        private Runnable decorateTask(Runnable task) {
            // not 100% sure about safety of this cast
            return new MyRunnable((ScheduledMethodRunnable) task);
        }

        private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

            private final ScheduledMethodRunnable runnable;
            private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

            public MyRunnable(ScheduledMethodRunnable runnable) {
                this.runnable = runnable;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(runnable.getMethod().toGenericString() + " " + counter.incrementAndGet());
                runnable.run();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        TaskScheduler taskScheduler = new MyTaskScheduler(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10));
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/1 * * * * *")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Running task in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for the answer

Comment: When I use '@Scheduled(cron = "0/1 * * * * *")', it works. When I use '@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)', it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: @AllenKerr - you have to override the remaining schedule* methods of concurrenttasksheduler to decorate the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AOP to intercept code before it enters any method annotated with `@Scheduled` and set the MDC. For good measure, it clears the MDC upon exiting the method.

Note the `atExecutionTimeInMyNamespace` pointcut, where you can optionally put in your own package namespace to limit to just use of @Scheduled in your own code (i.e. excluding its use in any 3rd party libs, however unlikely that may be).

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ScheduledTaskTracingAspect {

  @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled)")
  public void methodAnnotatedWithScheduled() {}

  @Pointcut("execution(* com.mycompany..*(..))")
  public void atExecutionTimeInMyNamespace() {}

  @Around("methodAnnotatedWithScheduled() && atExecutionTimeInMyNamespace()")
  public Object connectionAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    MDC.put("myId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    try {
      return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    finally {
      // Might as well clear all the MDC, not just the "myId"
      MDC.clear();
    }
  }

}
```